# Spring 4 entityManager configuration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am studying spring and currently integrating entityManager to be used. However, I keep on getting this error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBean' defined in class path resource [com/app/configuration/PersistenceJPAConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/archive/scan/spi/ScanEnvironment
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1648)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:463)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:413)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1399)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:828)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$241(TCPTransport.java:683)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$$Lambda$1/134399053.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/archive/scan/spi/ScanEnvironment
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:49)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
... 58 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.ScanEnvironment
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1313)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1164)
... 63 more
```

My configuration for JPA
I got this from http://www.baeldung.com/2011/12/13/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-3-1-and-jpa/.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceJPAConfig {

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(dataSource());
    em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "org.app.model" } );

    JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

    return em;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/SpringJPA");
    dataSource.setUsername("root");
    dataSource.setPassword("root");
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);

    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean
public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
    return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
}

Properties additionalProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
    return properties;
}
}
```

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/archive/scan/spi/ScanEnvironment` : have you included all Hibernate JARs needed ?

Comment: I have hibernate-core, hibernate-entitymanager and spring-data-jpa.

Comment: Some place you have used org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.ScanEnvironment. The jar containing this isn't in classpath.

Comment: @BilboBaggins How do I determine that?

Comment: search for it using IDE features :) :)

Comment: I searched it using Intellij IDEA, there were no occurrence of ScanEnvironment

Comment: If you could share a good article / guide about configuring EntityManager it would really help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with [Spring-boot](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html). The configuration is better and easier. You wouldn't set all the beans and datasource. Boot would configure all for you. You only have to configure the application.properties. [Here](https://github.com/netgloo/spring-boot-samples/tree/master/spring-boot-mysql-springdatajpa-hibernate) is a good example.